# Changing field type in a Django ModelFormset

Tags: django, django-forms, formset

In a Django ModelForm, you can change the widget type of a field like so:

```
class EntryForm(ModelForm):
    entity = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Entry
```

I can easily create a modelformset from the same model like so:

```
EntryFormSet = modelformset_factory(Entry)
```

But is there a way to include the input field type change change when creating a modelformset?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

EntryFormSet = modelformset_factory(Entry, form=EntryForm)

Comment: After setting it up as recommended above, passing entry_formset = EntryFormSet(prefix='entries') to render_to_response still displays all the fields. I'm still playing around with this.

Comment: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#controlling-which-fields-are-used-with-fields-and-exclude

Comment: Ah -- thanks. I expected it to inherit those from my EntryForm model, which also excluded some fields (which I left out from the example above for simplicity)

Answer (score 4):

`modelformset_factory` takes a keyword argument `form`, which -- I believe -- will let you pass your form class and have it used...